# FastAPI's auto generated OpenAPI file not valid according to Insomnia

Tags: swagger, fastapi, openapi, insomnia

I am trying to import an `openapi.json` into Insomnia to generate a collection, but Insomnia says it is not valid.

**Is there a difference in rulesets between FastAPI/Swagger and Insomnia? If not, what causes this difference in compatibility?**

Here's a trimmed down example of an automatically generated OpenAPI specification:

```json
{
    "openapi": "3.0.2",
    "info": {
        "title": "Test API",
        "description": "description",
        "contact": {
            "name": "example",
            "url": "https://example.com/contact-us/",
            "email": "example@example.com"
        },
        "license": {
            "name": "Copyright 2023 example"
        },
        "version": "0.0.1"
    },
    "paths": {
        "/test_build": {
            "get": {
                "tags": [
                    "Test endpoints"
                ],
                "summary": "Test",
                "description": "",
                "operationId": "test_build_get",
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Successful Response",
                        "content": {
                            "application/json": {
                                "schema": {}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "/api/search_something": {
            "get": {
                "tags": [
                    "Main endpoints"
                ],
                "summary": "Search something",
                "description": "",
                "operationId": "search_something_get",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "required": false,
                        "schema": {
                            "title": "something",
                            "maximum": 50.0,
                            "exclusiveMinimum": 0.0,
                            "type": "integer",
                            "default": 50
                        },
                        "name": "something",
                        "in": "query"
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Successful Response",
                        "content": {}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is rejected by Insomnia for many reasons, but here are some examples of errors and warnings:

- oas3-api-servers OpenAPI "servers" must be present and non-empty array.
- operation-tag-defined Operation tags must be defined in global tags.
- oas3-schema "exclusiveMinimum" property type must be boolean.
- oas3-valid-schema-example schema is invalid: data must have property minimum when property exclusiveMinimum is present

**Is there a way to make FastAPI's openapi.json file conform with Insomnia's ruleset?**

Comment: While not an answer to your question, according to the OpenAPI specification, `exclusiveMinimum` is a reference to `json-schema-validation`, which in turn defines: `The value of "exclusiveMinimum" MUST be a number, representing an exclusive lower limit for a numeric instance.` - so there seems to be different expectations of the format here.

Comment: @MatsLindh in my example it seems that `"exclusiveMinimum": 0.0` is a number. Also, this was automatically generated by FastAPI. My. Python model just has an attribute like so: `something: conint(gt=0)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> oas3-schema "exclusiveMinimum" property type must be boolean.

`exclusiveMinimum` and `exclusiveMaximum` being generated as numbers instead of booleans is a [known issue](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/4108) with Pydantic. Pydantic generates these keywords as numbers according to JSON Schema Draft 6+, but OpenAPI 3.0.x uses an earlier JSON Schema Draft 5 where the `exclusive*` keywords are booleans.

This won't be an issue if/when FastAPI and Pydantic migrate to OpenAPI 3.1 because it uses the latest JSON Schema.

But if you need to use OpenAPI 3.0.x, you have the following options.

#### Option 1: use `ge`/`le` instead of `gt`/`lt` (if suitable)

In case of **integer** parameters and schema fields, the easiest fix is to use the `ge`/`le` attributes ("greater/less than *or equal*") instead of `gt`/`lt` ("greater/less than"). For example, if the minimum value is 1 (inclusive), use `ge=1` instead of `gt=0`:

```py
something: int = Query(ge=1)
```

Pydantic translates `ge` to `minimum` and `le` to `maximum` without `exclusive*`.

#### Option 2: post-process the OpenAPI file

Another solution is to post-process your generated OpenAPI file (e.g. [as suggested here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/extending-openapi/)) and replace

```
"exclusiveMinimum": <value>
```

with

```
"minimum": <value>,
"exclusiveMinimum": true
```

Similarly, replace

```
"exclusiveMaximum": <value>
```

with

```
"maximum": <value>,
"exclusiveMaximum": true
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there an already built post-processor for FastAPI OpenAPI to valid OAPI JSON?

Comment: @mincom None that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps I just ran into this same issue, and followed the above suggestion as well to solve the issue locally. Below is a version of the solution I used.

```
import fastapi
from fastapi.openapi.utils import get_openapi 


app = fastapi.FastAPI()

def clean_property(prop: dict) -> None:
    for find, replace in [
        ("exclusiveMinimum", "minimum"),
        ("exclusiveMaximum", "maximum"),
    ]:
        if find in prop:
            prop[replace] = prop[find]
            prop[find] = True

def custom_openapi() -> dict:
    if app.openapi_schema:
        return app.openapi_schema

    openapi_schema = get_openapi(
        title="Custom title",
        version="3.0.1",
        description="Custom description",
        routes=app.routes,
    )

    for data in openapi_schema["paths"].values():
        for _method, method_data in data.items():
            for parameter in method_data.get("parameters", []):
                if "schema" in parameter:
                    clean_property(parameter["schema"])

    for schema in openapi_schema["components"]["schemas"].values():
        for prop in schema.get("properties", {}).values():
            clean_property(prop)

    app.openapi_schema = openapi_schema

    return app.openapi_schema

app.openapi = custom_openapi
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! In my case, I have something like 50 errors. In my post I just listed a few of them. So I would need a fairly big `custom_openapi`.