# Greater than (gt) and less than (lt) parameters in FastAPI Path() do not work in Swagger UI

Tags: validation, swagger, fastapi, swagger-ui, openapi

Versions used

- python 3.9.9
- FastAPI 0.95.1
- uvicorn 0.22.0
- firefox 102.8.0

In this example, the path parameter `item_id` is set up with a valid range > 100 (`gt=100`) and < 1000 (`lt=1000`).
However, it's not recognized in Swagger UI.
`ge` and `le` work fine.

```py
from typing import Annotated

from fastapi import FastAPI, Path

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
async def read_items(
    item_id: Annotated[int, Path(title="The ID of the item to get", gt=100, lt=1000)]
):
    return {"item_id": item_id}
```

with `gt` and `lt`, the constraints are neither shown in the UI nor enforced.
[image]

with `ge` and `le`, the constraints are both shown in the UI and enforced.
[image]

Comment: I'd like to bring attention to that the incorrect `exclusiveMinimum` and `exclusiveMaximum` specification in `openapi.json`, pointed out by Chris above, is already filed at https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/9140.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FastAPI's auto generated OpenAPI file not valid according to Insomnia](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75862523/113116)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with the [auto-generated OpenAPI schema](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/first-steps/?h=openapi#check-the-openapijson), which is used by Swagger UI to provide the [interactive API documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/features/#automatic-docs). You could see the schema directly at: http://127.0.0.1:8000/openapi.json. Given the example you provided, for `item_id: int = Path(title="The ID of the item to get", gt=100, lt=1000)` parameter, you would see:

```json
{...,
  "schema": {
    "title": "The ID of the item to get",
    "exclusiveMaximum": 1000,
    "exclusiveMinimum": 100,
    "type": "integer"
  },
  "name": "item_id",
  "in": "path"
}, ...
```

However, as described in [Swagger documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#numbers), in the case of using `gt` and `lt` (meaning that the `maximum` and `minimum` values should be excluded from the range), the OpenAPI shcema should instead look like this:

```json
{...,
  "schema": {
    "title": "The ID of the item to get",
    "maximum": 1000,
    "exclusiveMaximum": true,
    "minimum": 100,
    "exclusiveMinimum": true,
    "type": "integer"
  },
  "name": "item_id",
  "in": "path"
}...
```

Hence, `exclusiveMaximum` and `exclusiveMinimum` attributes should take a **boolean** value, not the actual number value itself. In order to exclude both the boundary values, both `exclusiveMaximum` and `exclusiveMinimum` should be set to `true`. This issue has previously been described [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/9140) and is meant to be resolved when/if FastAPI migrates to OpenAPI 3.1 (see [Helen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75876041/17865804) around this topic as well). Until then, you may want to have a look at the following solutions.

### Possible solutions

##### Solution 1

Instead of using `gt`/`lt`, you could use `ge`/`le`. If, for instance, `gt=100` and `lt=1000`, you could instead use `ge=101` and `le=999`. Example:

```py
item_id: int = Path(title="The ID of the item to get", ge=101, le=999)
```

##### Solution 2

One could load their own modified OpenAPI shcema, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71536816/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71958583/17865804), but even though Swagger UI would display the `minimum` and `maximum` values (if a modified schema was used, similar to the one demonstrated above), Swagger UI would still not make it clear to the user that  `minimum` and `maximum` values should be excluded (with *greater/less than* symbols, for instance). Also, if the user passed, for example, `1000` value to the `item_id` parameter, the validation would not take place in the frontend and Swagger UI would not display a validation error message (e.g., `Value must be less than 1000`)—which would happen if `ge` and `le` parameters wre used instead—but validation should rather take place in the backend, which would respond with a `422 Unprocessable Entity` error and an appropriate validation error message in the response body. Hence, there might be issues with both the generated OpenAPI shcema and Swagger UI as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. However, it seems to be a tricky issue to address.

Comment: Thanks again. I was looking for where to file a ticket. I was about to do it in swagger-ui github but it said "we can't accept bugs in the Swagger/OpenAPI specifications." I'll do that in the link you recommended.

Comment: I'd like to bring attention to that the incorrect `exclusiveMinimum` and `exclusiveMaximum` specification in `openapi.json`, pointed out by Chris above, is already filed at https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/9140.